# Tokens Are Always Invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

When trying to do a password reset or email confirmation, on the flow to run the method

```
var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Code, model.Password);
```

It never returns true. Fails with invalid token, even though I checked the token generated and the one passed via email myself. I am not sure if there is something else I am doing wrong. Below is how I generate the code to send via email

```
var newUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(requestData.Email);
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(newUser);
```

This is the same for sending a confirmation email token. I create the user via api call then try to confirm the email token on the IS server not sure if that adds a wrench in my process or not. I am looking for some help to figure out if my workflow to generate then email the token is incorrect and maybe I should be doing some additional work before.

Comment: Hi @kabuto178, not sure how is your whole code like. I suggest you can scaffold Identity to check the default generated reset password code.

Comment: If you are using two different processes then perhaps your aspnet core data protection is not the same for both apps?  I believe the token generation used by identity uses the aspnet core data protection for encrypt and decrypt operations so would need to configured the same for different apps wanting to encrypt in one and decrypt in another.

Comment: @Mark I see, I may have to do more digging to find out. I am still experimenting with the code